# Forms in BLoC architecture, or better way to create reactive form?

Tags: forms, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-bloc

I am new to flutter and streams also, I want to accomplish the best way how to create a form, which is sending post request to API and create object which has 6 fields.

I am trying to build form in BLoC architecture pattern, so I am using streams controllers. Just found out, that using streams and seState in combination is a bad idea.

So should I use a stream, in my BLoC, for each field in form? Is that a good practice? Using specific stream for each field seems weird to me, but I dont see any other option.

My question is, which way is the best to create dynamic and reactive forms?

I really appreciate every advice, thank you!